# вопрос по zeroOrOne instead null

Tags: smart-pointer

вобщем я не шибко программист еще. Мысль кажется неплохой, а вот как она показала бы себя в реальности - откуда мне знать.

Суть - зачем нам null когда мы подразумеваем что элемент либо есть, либо нет. Что если относится к такой переменной в смысле "массив из 0 или 1 элементов"? Тогда мы не теряем знания о типе - это в любом случае "сколько-то элементов данного типа".

рабочий пример на D, но смысл я думаю ясен.

```
void test2() {
    Widget2 container = new Widget2( null );
    Widget2 child = new Widget2( container );


    auto widget = container.parent; // 'zero' like a 'null'
    writeln( "widget is " ~ ( widget? "'one" : "'zero" ) ~ " widgets' \n=============================" );
    widget.processWidget2;              // <1>
    widget.doit( 1 );                   // <2>


    widget = child.parent;
    writeln( "\n\nwidget is " ~ ( widget? "'one" : "'zero" ) ~ " widgets' \n=============================" );
    widget.processWidget2;              // <3>
    widget.doit( 10 );                  // <4>

}
class Widget2
{
    this( Widget2 parent ) { this.parent = parent; }
    void doit( int x ) { writeln( "Widget.doit: ", x ); }
    zeroOrOne!Widget2 parent;
}
void processWidget2( zeroOrOne!Widget2 widget ) {
    writeln( "processWidget2" );
    write( "    " );

    widget.doit( 33 );
    if( !widget ) writeln( "widget is " ~ ( widget? "'one" : "'zero" ) ~ " widgets'" );

    writeln( "    end processWidget2" );
}
```

и вывод

```
/* output                 ( no output for <2> )

widget is 'zero widgets'
=============================
processWidget2                  // <1>
    widget is 'zero widgets'
    end processWidget2


widget is 'one widgets'
=============================
processWidget2                  // <3>
    Widget.doit: 33
    end processWidget2
Widget.doit: 10                 // <4>

*/
```

Comment: оставил сам вопрос не заданным - имеет эта мысль право на жизнь или нет. есть ли что то аналогичное по смыслу, и если да, то может ли кто-нибудь описать положительный\негативный опыт. или просто объяснить почему идея ни о чём.